# Trigger pipeline after AppCenter success

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I need to trigger a pipeline to begin once a specific AppCenter app has passed its 'launch-app' test. Ideally it would export the app to the pipeline and then I can begin testing in the pipeline.

I was hoping there would be a nice little extension for this but after much searching it seems its harder than I thought.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.